# Python - count number of elements that are equal between two columns of two dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two dataframes: `df1`, `df2`
that contain two columns, `col1` and `col2`. I would like to calculate the number of elements in column `col1` of `df1` that are equal to `col2` of `df2`. How can I do that?

Comment: u can do a ``inner merge`` between both the frames and get the length of the merged dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html?highlight=isins) `df1.col1.isin(df2.col2).sum()`:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': [1, 3, 5, 7]})

nb_comon_elements = df1.col1.isin(df2.col2).sum()

assert nb_comon_elements == 3
```

Be cautious depending on your use case because:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 7]})
df1.col1.isin(df2.col2).sum()
```

Would return 4 and not 2, because all `1` from `df1.col1` are present in `df2.col2`. If that's not the expected behaviour you could drop duplicates from `df1.col1` before testing the intersection size:

```py
df1.col1.drop_duplicates().isin(df2.col2).sum()
```

Which in this example would return 2.

To better understand why this is happening you can have look at what `.isin` is returning:

```py
df1['isin df2.col2'] = df1.col1.isin(df2.col2)
```

Which gives:

```py
   col1  isin df2.col2
0     1           True
1     1           True
2     1           True
3     2          False
4     7           True
```

Now `.sum()` adds up the booleans from column `isin df2.col2` (a total of 4 `True`).

Comment: I want it to return the number of elements that are equal without having to specify which element to check for.

Comment: Maybe just `df1.col1.isin(df2.col2).sum()` is sufficient?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "without having to specify which element to check".

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote? no? Just added the assertion to show it's working as expected on this example.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using pandas.

One way is to simply use `pd.merge` and merge on the second column, and return the length of that column.

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on="column_to_merge")
```

Pandas does an inner merge by default.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html